# log4j initialization failing in unix

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to initialize log4j below way when i  start component in unix.But it is complaining about not initialized properly.what will be the problem?

```
java -Xmx1024M -client -Xrs -Dname=test_comp  -Dlog4j.propertyfile=../etc/config/log4j.properties -Dcom.test.files.FieldComp=../etc/config/field.xml
```

below is log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, file, stdout

    log4j.category.com.opensymphony = ERROR

    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t-] %d{ISO8601} (%C:%L) - %m%n


    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10000KB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1

    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=ERROR
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t-] %d{ISO8601} (%C:%L) - %m%n
```

Regards,
Raj

Comment: Post the full stacktrace so that we can see what the exact issue is.

Comment: this is the stacktrace:log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger

Answer (score 0):

Name of the system property is `log4j.configurationFile` and not log4j.propertyfile. Check the  [log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) for more details.  For [version 1.2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) it is `log4j.configuration`

Comment: same working in windows, i also tried with log4j.configurationFile .my log4j version is:1.2.15